# How to retrieve an object indexed by strings with wildcards characters?

Tags: c++, data-structures, mqtt

In a process, I have a MQTT client thread (class MQTTManager) whose role is to manage subscriptions made by many objects (derived from a MQTTUser interface class).
Whenever a topic is published, the MQTTManager instance must retrieve and redirect the message to the corresponding object(s).

MQTT topics can have wildcards characters, and MQTTUser instances are often using this feature when they register to the MQTTManager.

I have trouble designing an efficient way to retrieve objects, i.e. without comparing every registered string and dealing with wildcards characters.

As a reminder, '+' is a wildcard for one topic level (word between two '/' characters), and '#' is a wildcard for multiple topic levels).
You can find `#` only at the end of a string. It just means "any topic level sequence until the end of string".

> Example:
>
> - A MQTTUser instance 'foo' registers to MQTTManager with string "**foo/#**"
> - Another instance 'bar' registers to MQTTManager with string "**bar/#**"
> - A third instance 'tricky' registers to MQTTManager with string "**+/class/+/temp/#**"
>
> If the topic "**foo/net/5**" is published, the MQTTManager instance should redirect the message to the 'foo' instance.
>
> A topic "**bar/class/5/temp/cpu/5**" would be redirected to 'bar' and 'tricky' instances.
>
> And finally, the topic "**flop/class/0**" wouldn't be send to any object.

I'm looking for a design where the MQTTManager instance would quickly find the relevant objects, without having to parse every registered strings. I confusely feel like a simple map structure won't be enough for that.

I use a C++17 compiler, so most modern C++ features are available.

Thank you for all your help.

EDIT:
OK, for anyone having a similar problem, here is my solution. I first have a topic level class :

```
class topicLevel {
public:
    topicLevel();

    void addUser(std::string const& topic, MQTTUser* user);
    void processTopic(std::string const &completeTopic, std::string const &topic, std::string const& payload, std::set<MQTTUser*> &alreadyFound);

private:
    std::map<std::string, topicLevel> registeredTopics;
    std::list<MQTTUser*> relevantUser;
};
```

This class holds the objects that subscribed to this topic level, as well as a map for sub topic level.

My MQTTManager class creates one instance of this class for the root topic :

```
class MQTTManager : public mqtt_client {
public:
    MQTTManager();
    virtual ~MQTTManager() override {}

    void registerUser(MQTTUser *user);
    virtual void on_message(std::string topic, std::string message) override;

private:
    topicLevel rootTopic;
};
```

From this point, MQTTUser instances are registered with the registerUser method :

```
void MQTTManager::registerUser(MQTTUser *user) {
    if (nullptr != user) {
        std::list<std::string> topics;
        user->getTopics(topics);
        for (auto const& t: topics) {
            if (t.empty() == false) {
                rootTopic.addUser(t, user);
                subscribe(t);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Each topic the MQTTUser wants to subscribe is processed by the root topic instance via the addUser method :

```
void topicLevel::addUser(std::string const& topic, MQTTUser* user) {
    std::string root, subTopics;
    extractRootTopic(topic, root, subTopics);
    if ((root.compare("#") == 0) || (root.empty() == true)) {
        relevantUser.push_back(user);
    } else {
        auto [ instance, success ] = registeredTopics.insert(std::make_pair(root, topicLevel()));
        instance->second.addUser(subTopics, user);
    }
}
```

This method first process the topic string, to extract the root topic (i.e. the first one) and the remaining of the string (i.e. the subtopics).
If the root topic is '#', or empty the user should be registered in the topicLevel instance.

Otherwise,the root topic becomes a key (index) for a new topicLevel instance, stored in a map. The 'addUser' method is then called on this new instance, with the subtopic string as argument.

From this point, the publications are ready to be processed.
When a topic is published, the MQTTManager instance calls the root topic instance method "processTopic" :

```
void MQTTManager::on_message(std::string topic, std::string message) {
    std::set<MQTTUser*> alreadyFound;
    rootTopic.processTopic(topic, topic, message, alreadyFound);
}
```

We use a set of MQTTUser (alreadyFound) to remind which relevantUser we already redirect the publication to. This caution is there in case a MQTTUser subscribed to multiple topics : there is a risk that one publication match many of these subscription. However, this publication should be processed only once by the MQTTUser instance.

The processTopic method is like this :

```
void topicLevel::processTopic(const std::string &completeTopic, std::string const &topic, std::string const& payload, std::set<MQTTUser *> &alreadyFound) {
    std::string root, subTopics;
    for (MQTTUser* user: relevantUser) {
        if (alreadyFound.find(user) == alreadyFound.end()) {
            alreadyFound.insert(user);
            user->on_message(completeTopic,payload);
        }
    }
    extractRootTopic(topic, root, subTopics);
    auto wildcardInstance = registeredTopics.find("+");
    if (wildcardInstance != registeredTopics.end()) {
        wildcardInstance->second.processTopic(completeTopic, subTopics, payload, alreadyFound);
    }
    auto rootInstance = registeredTopics.find(root);
    if (rootInstance != registeredTopics.end()) {
        rootInstance->second.processTopic(completeTopic, subTopics, payload, alreadyFound);
    }
}
```

When this method is called, the MQTTUser registered in this topicLevel instance should get the message : this is done in the first part of the function (if this wasn't done before).
Then we have to go on with the subtopics, so we extract the root topic to find the next topicLevel instance.
There is a small subtlety here : a topic registered with a wildcard ('+') will be considered as a potential candidate, so we first search for this character as a root topic index and call processTopic on the instance found (if any).
Finally, we look for a topicLevel instance with the root topic, and call processTopic on it, if found.

This is it ! Please make a comment if you have a better implementation, I'll edit my post.

Comment: Can `#` appear in the middle of the string?

Comment: No `#` must always be the last entry

Comment: Yes, you can find # only at the end of a string. It just means "any topic level sequence until the end of string".

Answer (score 1):

Something simple you can do is make a mapping with the first topic part as the key.  Your three example subscribers would be keyed as "foo", "bar", and "+".

Then make a mapping of topics to subscribers.  The key is the full topic name being published.

When you want to publish a topic, look it up in the second mapping.  If it's found, just send it to those subscribers.  If not, look up the first part of the topic in the first mapping (always including the subscribers whose first part is "+" or "#") and check all the subscriber patterns against the topic.  This is O(n) but you only do it once per new topic, so it's probably fine.

Comment: Thank you for this solution ! It gave me the idea that any topic published should be split by topic level, and each of them should be compared in a tree-like data structure, to quickly get the relevant candidates. I'll edit my answer with this implementation when I'm done.